# How to export inputted parameters with python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I apologies because I'm a new user for python tkinter.
It is possible to export data inputted with Entry function?
Currently the code works, but the value is not present in the "e1" output.
Thanks in advance

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except:
    import tkinter as tk
class Test():
   def __init__(self):
       self.root = tk.Tk()
       self.root.geometry('100x50')
       e1 = tk.Entry(self.root)
       e1.pack()
       self.e1 = e1.get()
       button = tk.Button(self.root,
                          text = 'Quit and take out values',
                          command=self.quit)
       button.pack()
       self.root.mainloop()   
       
   def quit(self):
       self.root.destroy()
app = Test()
print(app.e1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `e1.get()` right after `e1` is created.  So at that time there is nothing input and you should get an empty string.

You can get the entry value inside `quit()` function, but you need to rename `e1` to `self.e1`:

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except:
    import tkinter as tk

class Test():
   def __init__(self):
       self.root = tk.Tk()
       self.root.geometry('100x50')
       self.e1 = tk.Entry(self.root)
       self.e1.pack()
       button = tk.Button(self.root,
                          text = 'Quit and take out values',
                          command=self.quit)
       button.pack()
       self.root.mainloop()   
       
   def quit(self):
       self.value = self.e1.get()
       self.root.destroy()

app = Test()
print(app.value)
```